# Exception propagation in C#

Tags: c#, exception

Suppose I have three functions doA(), doB(), and doC() in a C# program where I know that doA() will call doB() which in turn calls doC().

Since doC() has to interact with a database, I know that it could very well generate exceptions that it won't be able to resolve that need to be brought to the user's attention.  At the moment, I have the code which might throw the error in a try / catch blow in doC() and then the call to doC() in doB() in another try / catch and similarly the call to doB() in doA() in try / catch block.  This allows me to just use throw; to kick the exception up to doA() where something can reasonably be done to display this to the user.

This seems a little like overkill though.  I am wondering if since I don't plan on dealing with the exception in doB() or doC() if I can just get rid of the try / catch blocks there.

Assuming there are no finally blocks involved, what is the best practice for dealing with situations like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your catch blocks are just like this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

then they are pointless indeed. You're not really handling the exception - don't bother with try/catch at all.

Personally I have very few try/catch blocks in my code - and although there are plenty of *implicit* try/finally blocks, most are due to `using` statements.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I would get rid of the try/catch blocks - just let the exception propagate up to the top level and then catch it there. Catching an exception just to rethrow with `throw;` is simply not useful, although the following variation is actually harmful as it destroys the stack trace information:

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    throw exception;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You only need to catch if you intend to do something (or are trying to stop propagation).  If you don't catch, it goes to the catch in the caller.  In your case, it seems like doA() (or possibly its caller, depending on where you can handle it) is the only function that needs try/catch.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions bubble up the call stack.

If the method where the exception happens doesn't handle it, the methods caller gets it. If the caller doesn't handle it, it goes further up the call stack until the framework handles it and crashes your application.

To answer your question: there is no need to rethrow an exception in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Type of exceptions you ll be catching can be different in every level, I m not sure what you are doing in 3 levels, but at the top of the stack you can only can 1 type of exception, in the lower level there might be different type of exception, which kinda forces u to use a broad exception type then a specific one, which might not have clear information in it.

So it depends on the types of Exceptions you ll be throwing.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, an exception should be caught the fewest number of times possible, it's actually a rather expensive operation to catch an exception.

The case might come up where you're crossing application layers, and might want one layer to log/rethrow, and the next layer up also needs to catch it.  But in your case, it's just one layer so I'd say at the highest place in the call stack where you can do something with the exception, log it and do your business logic.

Comment: Not getting into the true/falseness of your statement "it's actually a rather expensive operation to catch an exception", you'd be hard pressed to convince me that it actually matters.

Comment: It's not for me to tell you that the performance of your application matters.

Comment: Either you completely missed the point, or I didn't do an effective job of communicating it; it's very likely the latter so please accept my apologies for that. I'll elaborate. I seriously doubt that the performance-characteristics of catching an exception EVER matters. For the most part, it's unlikely to be a bottleneck in any realistic application; remember, exceptions are for exceptional situations. Additionally, an exception usually indicates that the state of the system is bad and at that point, performance almost surely doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In short the answer to your question is yes.  The only reason to catch an exception is to do something with it.  If you can't do anything useful with it in DoC() then just let it bubble up.

It is always a good practice to have try catch blocks at the entry points to your code (typically in event handlers in a win forms app) so that nothing goes uncaught.  At that point what you can do with it is tell the user.

However, you may also want to put some lower level handlers in place as appropriate if they can take reasonable action. For example, in doC() you might want to catch exceptions that have to do with deadlocks and retry.  At some level you may also want to catch  constraint errors and throw more meaningful user targeted errors in their place.  I have a [blog post about that here](http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/pattern-for-better-error-handling).